# For multiple instances of the same object, are member variables stored at the same offset?

Tags: c++

Say I have a struct Foo:

```
struct Foo
{
    char a;
    int b;
} Foo1, Foo2;
```

The compiler may insert padding so that Foo::a is stored at the start of the object's memory, and Foo::b is stored at an offset of 0x04 (say on a 32-bit system for example).

If I create multiple instances of this object Foo1 and Foo2, will they always have the same padding? Is there ever a case where Foo1::b is stored at offset 0x04 and Foo2::b is stored at offset 0x08 for example?

Comment: Any code that works with `Foo::b` must rely on guarantees regarding the layout of `Foo`.

Comment: @DrewDormann Not necessarily. Consider the dynamic pointer adjustment needed to support virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For multiple instances of the same object, are member variables stored at the same offset?

Yes.

> If I create multiple instances of this object Foo1 and Foo2, will they always have the same padding?

Yes.

> Is there ever a case where Foo1::b is stored at offset 0x04 and Foo2::b is stored at offset 0x08 for example?

No.

---

This assumption holds only within the program. Compile the program on another system, and the offset can be different there.

Comment: Appreciate the quick, concise answer

Answer (score 2):

Consider [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof):

> ```
> #define offsetof(type, member) /*implementation-defined*/
> ```
>
> The macro `offsetof` expands to an integral constant expression of type `std::size_t`, the value of which is the offset, in bytes, from the
> beginning of an object of specified type to its specified subobject,
> including padding if any.

`offsetof` relies on compiler internals, though the offset of a member of some type is a constant expression.

Comment: This is helpful to know, thank you